# unable to send data from HTML form to Node server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have setup a simple HTML form as below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Echo server</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="/">
            <input type="text" id="keyword" name="keyword" />
            <input type="submit" value="echo" id="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {

        console.log(req.params);  // logged as {}
        res.writeHead(200);
        //req.pipe(res);       // throws error
        res.write('abc');      // works
        res.end();

});

app.listen(8080);
```

I am unable to access the parameters send from the form.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The route itself does not contain any parameter, so how you can expect params in cosole. If you are trying to get form data, you should use req.body

Comment: `req.body` gave me `undefined`.

Comment: You need to install parser module like body-parser(https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser). Also to make your development easier please install node-inspector to debug the node server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you would need the [body-parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) if you dont want to pull the data out of the http headers yourself.

Then you dont need to access the params as you dont have any, but the body of the request with `req.body`.